# Creating view table of columns from multiple select statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have a view (view1) with the following data of queries and table name such as:

[image]

and I want to create a view that essentially takes all these select statements and combines the columns without any joins or unions. What I have coded is:

```
select * from 
(select a from table1) as aa,
(select d from table1) as dd,
(select e from table1) as ee;
```

This query runs with no errors but the actual data shows duplicates. I've seen multiple examples but with joins or unions which did not give me the expected results as well.

Example:

This is table1

[image]

and after running the queries in my view I would want to get:
[image]

I know I can easily just do a a simple query such as:

```
select a,d,e from table1
```

however, I cannot change the data in my view1.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is entirely unclear what you want to do.  Given your query, why would you be surprised at duplicates?

Comment: Unless all of you tables have a single row per table it will return duplicates of course. If you were a DBMS how do you decide which single row from the entire table you need to return? Generally such "merge" of scalar queries is a design flaw and potential problem

Comment: That query does not run with no errors.  'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"'

Comment: I updated the original question

Comment: There is no way to do that unless you know the primary key of the table and use it in a join condition.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Substring(x.a_b_e, 1,Charindex(',', x.a_b_e)-1) as a ,

Substring(x.a_b_e, Charindex(',', x.a_b_e)+1,Charindex(',', x.a_b_e)-1 )b,

Substring(x.a_b_e, Charindex(';', x.a_b_e)+1,LEN(x.a_b_e) )d
from
(
select a+','+b+';'+e as a_b_e from #test
)x
```

Comment: yea the issue is that I'm looking for a way to perform this without joins because of the way that the stored procedure is structured in which I'm combining multiple select statements

Comment: This is invalid standard SQL and won't work with Postgres

Comment: I am using MSSQL . But Did you get the idea_?  First I merged the columns then split with using substring function.I don't know postgres standards. Unfortunately, I cannot help.